# Detect emails and response with a mail

Tags: java, android

If i got any email I want to response with a email from my code. 
Am new to java, Is it possible with any api to detect mails?

I saw javamail api in this we can read and send mail. In this we need to pass server host. To read hotmail emails what host name we need to pass?

I find the following code.

```
Properties props =System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol","imaps");
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("server hostname","username","password");
```

can u prefer any tutorials for that and property key values  and server hosts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-receiving-email-using-java-mail-api

here the solution to read mails

Comment: Is it any specific tutorial for server host.

Answer (score 0):

For reading mail

http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/06/reading-email-using-javamail-api-example.html

and get the To Address and send mail using

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm